# Order objects of objects in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to sort an object with objects in, and order by date. I get my objects from an API who delivers their API like this:

```
{
  "2529354": {
    "id": "2529354",
    "name": "Burton Albion-Barnsley",
    "tournament_stageFK": "850172",
    "startdate": "2017-10-31T19:45:00+00:00",
    "status_type": "notstarted",
    "status_descFK": "1",
    "n": "1",
    "ut": "2017-06-21T10:32:10+00:00",
    "tournamentFK": "11549",
    "tournament_templateFK": "48",
    "sportFK": "1",
    "tournament_stage_name": "Championship",
    "tournament_name": "2017/2018",
    "tournament_template_name": "England 2",
    "sport_name": "Soccer"
  },
  "2529355": {
    "id": "2529355",
    "name": "Cardiff City-Ipswich Town",
    "tournament_stageFK": "850172",
    "startdate": "2017-10-31T20:45:00+00:00",
    "status_type": "notstarted",
    "status_descFK": "1",
    "n": "1",
    "ut": "2017-06-21T10:32:10+00:00",
    "tournamentFK": "11549",
    "tournament_templateFK": "48",
    "sportFK": "1",
    "tournament_stage_name": "Championship",
    "tournament_name": "2017/2018",
    "tournament_template_name": "England 2",
    "sport_name": "Soccer"
  },
  "2529364": {
    "id": "2529364",
    "name": "Reading-Nottingham Forest",
    "tournament_stageFK": "850172",
    "startdate": "2017-10-31T19:00:00+00:00",
    "status_type": "notstarted",
    "status_descFK": "1",
    "n": "1",
    "ut": "2017-06-21T10:32:11+00:00",
    "tournamentFK": "11549",
    "tournament_templateFK": "48",
    "sportFK": "1",
    "tournament_stage_name": "Championship",
    "tournament_name": "2017/2018",
    "tournament_template_name": "England 2",
    "sport_name": "Soccer"
    }
};
```

It could be hard to notice, but the startdate is different in those 3 objects. 
The API delivers like 17 objects, or games in this context, and they are not in order. I have tried using the sort-function, but as it is for arrays it doesn't really work.

Is there a possibility to sort it with Object.keys(object) or something similar?

Comment: the immortal question of sorting objects. no, and yes, and in this case no, because you have integers, which are sorted by default ascending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sort this object as the properties are the keys, and therefore not sortable.  You can push the individual objects into an array and sort that instead though...

```js
var data = {
  "2529354": {
    "id": "2529354",
    "name": "Burton Albion-Barnsley",
    "startdate": "2017-10-31T19:45:00+00:00"
  },
  "2529355": {
    "id": "2529355",
    "name": "Cardiff City-Ipswich Town",
    "startdate": "2017-10-31T20:45:00+00:00"
  },
  "2529364": {
    "id": "2529364",
    "name": "Reading-Nottingham Forest",
    "startdate": "2017-10-31T19:00:00+00:00"
    }
};

var dataArray = [];

for (var i in data) {
  dataArray.push(data[i]);
}

dataArray.sort(function(x, y) {
  var xDate = new Date(x.startdate);
  var yDate = new Date(y.startdate);
  
  if (xDate < yDate) return -1
  else if (xDate > yDate) return 1
  else return 0;
});

console.log(dataArray);
```

**Note:** I trimmed the data for display purposes.  Just use the whole thing when you use it.

Comment: Alright, great to know.
Thank you for your solution, this works great.

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out the order of the keys and put them in an array like so:

```
var sortedKeys = Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(data[b].startdate) - new Date(data[a].startdate);
});
```

Then you can access your data in the sorted order like this

```
sortedKeys.each(function (key) {
    // do something with data[key] 
});
```